# WPF navigation using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, navigation

I want to know some things regarding navigation using MVVM.
[image: High Level UI Description]

Q1: Clicking in the Login Button if the authentication is ok, I want to open a completely new window, how I can do this without loosing the MVVM pattern. (I know the simple approach NewWindow w = new NewWindow(), show & hide and its ok) but this is so terrible that I have nightmares thinking about it. How can I do it?

Q2: The recovery button I want to completely reshape the login page, two have new text boxes and two buttons (submit recovery and cancel) using cancel I want to show the login again. How can I do it?

What I know: having two buttons in the same MainView and loading different views but the buttons have to stay there like a web page (this is a desktop app in the first iteration, will evolve to mobile as well).

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF/XAML is an extraordinary technology, there are many ways to do the same thing and even the simplest of explanations is too complicated to deliver on a forum like SO. To fully understand WPF, MVVM and XAML you need to look at example code and lots of it, you need to pick it apart and see how its working then modify it to do something else, strip parts out to implement in your own code and follow tutorials. Only by doing that 24/7/52 can you expect to become familiar with it.....

I'm not going to post any code here coz there is just too much. So here is a download to just about the simplest example I could come up with

http://www.mediafire.com/download/3bubiq7s6xw7i73/Navigation1.rar

the example is a modification of Rachel Lim example. It  simply contains Views and ViewModels, there are no Models or data. It demonstrates switching between two different Views. Download and un-RAR it (with win RAR) You will need to step though the code, figure out what its doing and how its doing it then modify it to suit your needs... Or modify your needs to suit the code.....

Maybe as your first task, Using my example code from the download link, you should try to add a third view plus code\Button to switch between three views....

Good luck

Comment: Hi Monty thanks for your suggestion. Actually I already found this blog of Rachel, is very good and has good explanation for the normal case but in my case the MainView opens with the LoginView, if I click the recovery all the stuff changes there is no button that stays equal, so I can't find similarity. I'm learning this by trial and error and this is really tricky :D

Comment: My two questions are highlighted here in different colors. The arrows represent the behavior I'm looking for. i.imgur.com/cIJJH5i.png  I hope having more clear my doubt

Comment: thanks a lot for your example. It has the behavior I want, now I will loose a few hours trying to really understand what happens beneath the hood. Actually that is the final behavior in this case. I need to have another view that is the register view. I will work on it. Really thanks for all your help. You put a simple message box. If I open a new window there is not considered a break of the MVVM pattern right?

Comment: Yes it will, your 'new window' will need to be implemented in the same way as the first two... Look in Base_View\ViewModel for the code that already manages the existing windows, Also look at the existing Button for LogOn in LogOn_View, that will need to look similar to the Recovery Button in the same View....

Comment: Although having said that, you could launch a new window I guess and implement new code for more View\ViewModels as in the Base_View.... the main thing is to keep the separation between View and ViewModel AND keep the complexity of the application to a minimum... remember that at some point in the future someone else might have to work on your code.... lol, might be you!!!

Comment: If I do  GeneralWindow gw = new GeneralWindow();            gw.Show();
            this.Hide(); in the OnLogCommand (logon_viewmodel) . I'm keeping the MVVM approach?

Comment: Actually and answering myself I don't think so, because I have to import the view.

Comment: Yeah, that would work... GeneralWindow would have a GeneralWindow_ViewModel (same as Base_View\Base_ViewModel) in there (gw View and ViewModel) you would implement more View\ViewModels in exactly the same way as in the Base_View\Base_ViewModel...

Comment: But if do that I will have to import the view to the viewModel and that is not very MVVMish right? Do you have suggestions? I saw some examples using the messenger and I understood them but they use code-behind the view and I like this approach of no code-behind.

Comment: I have modified the example in the download to correct some errors and now also demonstrates a 'Main' view that hosts several 'Content' views... my personal preference is to have a single Base_view that hosts all the other views (User Controls) and therefore having only one lump of code to handle Views\ViewModels and switching between them.. the analogy is of a web page that simply replaces it's content in response to the user clicking buttons\links....

Comment: I don't have words to thank you for your time and answer, this is perfect. Now I will be able to understand the navigation completely. I want just to put my mind at ease in one stuff in your implementation you don't create a new window right? I will have to create another window and not only change views

Comment: Creating another 'window' will mean having to replicate existing code already in Base_View. You can see in Main_ViewModel how I have used the existing functionality\objects that have already been created in the Base_View, to extend the application and display 3 new UserControls (MainV1, 2 & 3) within the Main_View itself. This keeps the whole application contained and conforms to MVVM. So rather than creating a new 'Window' you should create a new UserControl and display that using the mechanism that already exists in Base_View....

Comment: The art of XAML is to use the components (StackPanel, Grid etc.) to create a UI that is self contained, this is unlike a WinForms application where you would simply create new forms willy nilly... In fact, if you try to apply WinForms UI logic to WPF you'll end up with unmaintainable spaghetti code... I have see it....

Comment: I think I will use your approach. I already understood all the communication I will have in my whole app I don't think I will have more complicate stuff. Thanks for the teachings. Stay sharp

Comment: digging deeper in the code I put a breakpoint in the LoginCommand and never the application enters there, what is the point of having that messaging system if is not used? I forgot something?

Comment: sorry for the late answer, but I started working and this week has been really a mess. Answering your question I double checked the code and I found that you are using the Relay Command, so never mind. I missed something. I would like to ask you something about binding. Because in the Rachel Lim website she instantiates the model in the view, but that is not very MVVMish right? How do you do?

Comment: In Rachel Lim's MVVM example she has bound a ContentControl to CurrentProduct property (which will hold the currently selected instance of a ProductModel) in the ProductViewModel class …..

Comment: Hi Monty, thanks for being relentless trying to share knowledge with me. She has this: <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductModel}"> she is connecting the Model to the View Right? And she fires somekind of event OnPropertyChanged in the Model. I tought that every events will have to be implemented in the ViewModel. Can you clarify please?

Comment: OK Yeah, she is using the ProductModel class simply as a template (that line might also fire the ProductModel constructor if there is one)...  She says... the ProductView.xaml is just a ResourceDictionary that contains the 'templates' (two DataTemplate) for how to draw both the ProductModel and ProductViewModel objects. That's OK for MVVM. It's one way of doing it, and as I say, there are many ways to do the same thing…..

Comment: Yes,a lot. I'm searching the web for hours trying to make sense and experimenting the approaches that I find. What I'm thinking in doing: use the Models as Handlers for my webservices. Call the webservices from the viewModels deserialize them to the models. Use the data template of the models. Is this ok? I never tought that this will be so difficult, I made the app in two weeks in winforms in this I don't think I can do it that fast.

Comment: Yeah sounds OK.... again from Rachel's Blog... Models are typically either plain data models (think of something like a database row), or they are domain models which represents the state of something at run time. They usually only contain properties and basic validation related to that single model object itself. They are the building blocks used by the rest of the code when constructing the application..... A Model can exist on its own or as a collection<Model> OfModels.....

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you have to ask yourself who is responsible for opening a new Window. One might say that the UI is responsible for opening a new Window, regardless of the data in the ViewModel, therefore there is no problem in a button opening a new Window(), as there is no data actually involved. Do you need to open or close a window by manipulating an IsClose data item? I mean, really, do you find any useful scenario where you might need that? Then the ViewModel would be involved.

For the second question, you press some buttons and then some part of the UI changes. You have to ask yourself if any important part of the ViewModel changes when you do that, or is it just a case of having some IsOpen or IsShown variable that shows or hides some controls that are already connected to the underlying ViewModel.

There is no one-to-one relationship between Views and ViewModels. You may have many to many or you can have one huge ViewModel connecting to all Views. The point of MVVM is not to make the UI behave in a certain way, but to govern the logic of the application. The UI should then mould itself on that.

Comment: First of all thank you for your time here. Now straight to the point. I will have some logic in the firstViewModel using some webservice will authenticate the input of the user in the textBoxes. After that I will have some Object in the next window that will contain the response of this authentication User(idUser,name, nickname, etc...). Do you think I can open the window like a button open window? Sounds kinda strange.

Comment: The second question, I know how to change stuff in the view using the MVVM pattern but I have to maintain some buttons in the main view in my case I have a MainView that implements the LoginView as current view but if I want to do a password recovery all the stuff changes.... MainView implements the RecoveryView. From the recovery view I should be able to go to the loginView again...

Comment: I see MVVM like this: the UI adapts to the data in order to display it to the user and react to their actions. Opening or closing a Window is akin to making it visible or changing a color or showing a button. It's still UI. The fact that you have a window that opens another window is just a graphical implementation detail that might have nothing to do with the underlying data. With a different UI you might choose to display the same viewmodel differently and that should not change the viewmodel.

Comment: As for the second part... WPF is so great because it went away from inheritance and focused on composition. Perhaps your views should compose themselves out of separate modular subviews that would know how to take into consideration the underlying data?

Comment: I will open the View using the normal command of a new window and inside that window I will use a normal approach to the MVVM pattern... To the second part I understand what you said of modular subviews but for doing that I have to maintain one part of the MainView right? I want to do a completely new View but without changing the window or maintaining any content of the first. Can you give me some hints ? Thanks

Comment: A "view" is just a FrameworkElement with a DataContext on it, it's not necessarily a Window. Views can contain other views, Windows can contain elements bound to viewmodels without themselves being Views, etc.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking but I still didn't understand and can I reshape completely without maintaining at least one button calling the views :( really confusing concepts

Answer (score 0):

It is appropriate to use `DataTemplates` if you want to dynamically switch `Views` depending on the `ViewModel`:

```
<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelA}">
         <localControls:ViewAUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelB}">
         <localControls:ViewBUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
   <Window.Resources>
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Window>
```

If `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelA`, then `ViewA` will be displayed and `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelB`, then `ViewB` will be displayed.

Let me show an example where it can be seen where you should put `DataTemplates`:

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleMVVMExample.ApplicationView"
        ...The code omitted for the brevity...
        Title="Simple MVVM Example with Navigation" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelA}">
         <localControls:ViewAUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelB}">
         <localControls:ViewBUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfViewModels}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                                Margin="2,5"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentDataTemplateViewModel}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And I highly recommend you pay attention to Prism framework. [This tutorial is very nice.](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: Hi StepUp, thanks for your answer. This is actually the template I'm using but if you noticed you have to have always a button to make the changes and in my case the main view don't have the button. MainView opens with the LoginView, if I click the recovery all the stuff changes there is no button that stays equal... How can I solve this?

Comment: @Antoine If I understand correctly, you mean that there is no button to change view at `MainView`. Am I right? Maybe just by adding button to change view?

Comment: I will try to clarify my second question. I have 3 Views (Login and Recovery) and the Main View. So the app starts and the mainview is loaded, the mainview will load the loginview right away, because is the first view that the user saws. Then from there I can either login or recovery. If I click the recovery I want that the login view disappears (the image I posted is the login view) and the new RecoveryView to load. So I don't really maintain any button whatsoever. I hope now that I was able to put my doubt more clear =)

Comment: My two questions are highlighted here in different colors. The arrows represent the behavior I'm looking for. http://i.imgur.com/cIJJH5i.png