# Simple way to navigate through windows in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I know this is like the 100th time someone posted this question, but I still have troubles with this. I have two windows Login.xaml and Users.xaml. All I want to do is to navigate to Users.xaml when I click on Login button. It has to respect MVVM pattern.

I would really appreciate the help.

EDIT:

I am looking for a bit simpler way. Maybe this could explain my issue better. For example, I know how to do it using UWP.  When I was navigating in UWP, I had Helper classes like NavigationService, CommandHandler, RelayCommand etc, and I was navigating in ViewModel classes. Example, if I wanted to navigate to the registration page by clicking on a button registration on a login page, I would do it in LoginViewModel class by adding this

```
 private ICommand register;
public ICommand RegisterCommand
{
   get
   {
       return register ?? (register = new CommandHandler(() => Register(), 
       true));
   }
}
public void Register()
{
    ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(Registration), null);
}
```

After that, I bind a button to RegisterCommand, and that would solve it. Is there a way in WPF like this in UWP? For me, it is the simplest and understandable way of doing it, but I am not sure how to implement it in WPF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF navigation using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375917/wpf-navigation-using-mvvm)

Comment: The question gets a better answer if it would mention some of the hundreds of approaches that were taken into account so we can elaborate from that starting point.

Comment: I understand there are lots of ways, I edited the post to clear it a bit. And I have seen the example, but still, it is not what I am looking for. But thank you.